# Tmux waits after switching panes

Tags: tmux

I have been using tmux for a while now, but this issue only seemed to really appear after switching machines.

When switching panes directionally using prefix + arrow keys, tmux waits for a little while after each directional keypress to see if you add any directional keypresses. This is easily observed by pushing prefix and then mashing left and right when you have two panes arranged horizontally. It will accept additional left+right spam as pane-changes indefinitely, provided you don't leave much time between them.

However for me, its an extremely common case that the first thing i want to do after switching panes, is re-run the last command run in that terminal (up-arrow). Because of this wait-and-capture business that tmux does when switching panes, i have to wait more than a second before pushing up arrow or else it will gobble up my keypress. Is there a configuration option to shorten this time? It's starting to get very annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tmux is pretty flexible: all of my example keystroke are based on a default configuration (in OpenBSD).  This will probably work on your machine if you are the administrator/installer and haven't tinkered with customizing keystrokes, but the keystrokes I mention are not guaranteed to work with all tmux installations.  If people have tinkered with customizations, then hopefully those same people can also compensate to get these directions to work with the customizations.

There is an option called repeat-time.  You may wish to just turn the feature off.  Notice that if you type Ctrl-B ?, then a list of commands is shown.  Many of those commands just start with "bindkey", but the arrow keys start with "bindkey -r".  The -r says that a repeat time should be used.

> Ctrl-B :unbind Right

Beware: You might be tempted to do this:

> Ctrl-B :bind Right selectpane -R

However, when doing so, it seems the -r (after the word bind) gets auto-inserted.  Pressing

> Ctrl-B ?

will run "lsk" and show you the current setting, including -r getting inserted back in.  I haven't figured out why yet; it might be something specific to arrow keys.  The man page does say "Repeat is enabled for the default keys bound to the resize-pane command."  The resize-pane uses Ctrl-arrows.

> Ctrl-B :set repeat-time 1
> Ctrl-B :show

That sets the value to 1 millisecond.  The downside is that there seems to be little flexibility: that seems to be one option that universally affects all commands.  However, you might not be desiring such flexibility anyway, and so that may be a usable solution which you find is perfectly satisfactory.

Once you find something you like, be sure to edit a tmux configuration file so that this can happen rather automatically, without you needing to type in these keystrokes each time.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was most helpful. For now I will most likely set repeat-time to 1 as suggested. If I ever discover a way to disable repeat for only the arrow keys I will post it here

Answer (score 0):

Can't leave a comment, so I'll post this update here.  This issue appears to have been fixed, and simply binding the new keys works (at least as of version 2.8-3).  It also appears that tmux now unbinds automatically, so these four settings will fix the problem:

```
bind-key Left select-pane -L
bind-key Right select-pane -R
bind-key Up select-pane -U
bind-key Down select-pane -D
```